# Add dynamic series

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts plugin and I have two array, here is an example of my arrays:

> array1: Serie1, Serie2, Serie3
>   array2: 20, 30, 40

What I want to do is use this array in series options, array 1 as serie name and array 2 as serie value, I could do this manually but in the future maybe array1 is going to have more values and also array2.

```
$('#Chart').highcharts({
     title: {
        text: 'Example'
     },
     xAxis: {
        labels:
        {
          enabled: false
        }
     },
     yAxis: {
         allowDecimals: true,
         min: 0,
         title: {
              text: 'Results'
         }
      },
      credits: {
         enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
         reversed: true
      },
      series: [{
          name: array1[x],
          data: array2[x].map(function (value) {
             return Number(value);
          })
      }]
});
```

I tried using a for loop but I think that is not possible use this inside series option. Also I'm trying using a for loop outside the highcharts code and using a string var concatenating the above code but I'm not pretty sure about this, here is my code:

```
var constructor = "";
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      constructor += "name: '"+ array1[i] + "',";
      constructor += "data: " + array2[i] + ".map(function (value) {"
      constructor += "return Number(value);";
})
```

Comment: When array1 and array2 are modified , do a chart refresh ,  the changes should be reflected.

Comment: Create series before chart creation. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/job9dq7j/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the graph without series and then in a separate function you can do iterations on the array to get the data correctly and dynamically add the series in this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    chart.addSeries({
        name: array1[i],
        data: [array2[i]]
    }, false);
}
chart.redraw();
```

Not tested but the idea is that